Unable to run barebones Azure Function in VS Code
I am getting this error when pressing F5 in VS Code:

C:\Users\Alex .nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\2.0.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(136,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateFunctionMetadata" task failed unexpectedly.
[C:\Repos\k.Integration.ocommMessages\k.Integration.ocommMessages.csproj]
C:\Users\Alex.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\2.0.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(136,5):
error MSB4018: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '\?\C:  \Repos\k.Integration.ocommMessages\obj\Debug\net8.0\WorkerExtensions' because it is being used by another process. [C:\Repos\k.Integration.ocommMessages\k.Integration.ocommMessages.csproj]
C:\Users\Alex.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\2.0.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(136,5): error MSB4018:
at System.IO.FileSystem.RemoveDirectoryInternal(String fullPath, Boolean topLevel, Boolean allowDirectoryNotEmpty) [C:\Repos\k.Integration.ocommMessages\k.Integration.ocommMessages.csproj]
C:\Users\Alex.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\2.0.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(136,5): error MSB4018:
at System.IO.FileSystem.RemoveDirectoryRecursive(String fullPath, WIN32_FIND_DATA& findData, Boolean topLevel) [C:\Repos\k.Integration.ocommMessages\k.Integration.ocommMessages.csproj]
C:\Users\Alex.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\2.0.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(136,5): error MSB4018:
at System.IO.FileSystem.RemoveDirectory(String fullPath, Boolean recursive) [C:\Repos\k.Integration.ocommMessages\k.Integration.ocommMessages.csproj]
C:\Users\Alex.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\2.0.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(136,5): error MSB4018:
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.ExtensionsCsprojGenerator.RecreateDirectory(String directoryPath) in D:\a_work\1\s\sdk\Sdk\ExtensionsCsprojGenerator.cs:line 54 [C:\Repos\k.Integration.ocommMessages\k.Integration.ocommMessages.csproj]
C:\Users\Alex.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\2.0.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(136,5): error MSB4018:
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.ExtensionsCsprojGenerator.Generate() in D:\a_work\1\s\sdk\Sdk\ExtensionsCsprojGenerator.cs:line 46 [C:\Repos\k.Integration.ocommMessages\k.Integration.ocommMessages.csproj]
C:\Users\Alex.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\2.0.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(136,5): error MSB4018:
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Tasks.GenerateFunctionMetadata.Execute() in D:\a_work\1\s\sdk\Sdk\Tasks\GenerateFunctionMetadata.cs:line 53 [C:\Repos\k.Integration.ocommMessages\k.Integration.ocommMessages.csproj]
C:\Users\Alex.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\2.0.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(136,5): error MSB4018:
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\Repos\k.Integration.ocommMessages\k.Integration.ocommMessages.csproj]
C:\Users\Alex.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\2.0.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(136,5): error MSB4018:
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [C:\Repos\k.Integration.ocommMessages\k.Integration.ocommMessages.csproj]

I created a new function app in VS Code, using .NET 8.0 LTS. I added a .gitignore and a few c# classes. I tried to run it and got the error above. I've restarted VS Code and my machine, but the error persists.
What am I doing wrong?
I've attempted :
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk --prerelease
dotnet outdated
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-outdated
dotnet outdated --update

My .csproj looks ok:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <!-- Application Insights isn't enabled by default. See https://aka.ms/AAt8mw4. -->
    <!-- <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" /> -->
    <!-- <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.0.0" /> -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Please note that I've tried other Azure Function projects in VS Code that I know were bug free, and now they fail with the same issue.
I am able to open and run this project using Visual Studio 2022 but not vscode.

@Itallmakescents it runs with visual studio 2022 without issue.

yessir i restarted and no updates

"because it is being used by another process" - yeah, something is locking your file(s), restart your computer and try again. oh, you could try to find whoever locking the file(s) using these - i normally just dig around using process explorer..

I do agree with @BagusTesa, that some process is using it or locking it. Try restarting the machine and then also check which process is blocking the folder, then unblock it.
